# Merging CSV data empty

Tags: python, csv, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

left = 'E:\out\outfile.csv'
right = 'E:\in\station-info.csv'
output = 'E:\out\Concatenated-Merge.csv'
left_df = pd.read_csv(left)
right_df = pd.read_csv(right, converters={'USAF': str, 'WBAN': str})
right_df["USAF_WBAN"] = right_df["USAF"] + "-" + right_df["WBAN"]
merged_df = pd.merge(left_df, right_df.ix[:, ["USAF_WBAN", "STATION NAME", "LAT", "LON"]], left_on="ID", right_on="USAF_WBAN")
merged_df.to_csv(output)
print(merged_df.head())
```

Returns an empty DataFrame, I can watch it take the data from both csv files and it creates new csv file but the columns are empty.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, Year, Month, Day, Hour, Temp, DewTemp, Pressure, WinDir, WindSpeed, Sky, Precip1, Precip6, ID, USAF_WBAN, STATION NAME, LAT, LON]
Index: []
```

Comment: Could you make [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you have a syntactic mistake in the `right_df.ix[:,` - are you sure that's correct?

Comment: Can you include the output of `left.head()` and `right.head()`? I have a feeling your data is not being read by Pandas. Also, can you double check it is `pd.merge()` and not `df.merge()`?

Comment: @ AustinHastings .ix splitting right_df the ':' is letting it know that I want all the rows.

Comment: @ Kartik printed out .head() of both it's reading the data, I think your right about the df.merge() still returns an empty csv though.

Comment: @ Kartik Tried the left_df.merge() didn't work. Think merged_df = pd.DataFrame.merge(....) but like I said still returns empty set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your code slightly modified:

```
import pandas as pd

left = 'E:/out/outfile.csv'
right = 'E:/in/station-info.csv'
output = 'E:/out/Concatenated-Merge.csv'
left_df = pd.read_csv(left)
right_df = pd.read_csv(right, converters={'USAF': str, 'WBAN': str})
right_df["USAF_WBAN"] = right_df["USAF"] + "-" + right_df["WBAN"]
merged_df = left_df.merge(right_df.ix[:, ["USAF_WBAN", "STATION NAME", "LAT", "LON"]], left_on="ID", right_on="USAF_WBAN")
merged_df.to_csv(output)
print(merged_df.head())
```